# Manipulation and Touch events not firing, but mouse events do?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, multi-touch

I have a Samsung LD220Z multi touch monitor, and when I'm experimenting with some WPF and touch features the touch events arent firing. The mouse down event seems to be firing however.

Does this mean that I have to take into account that not all touch screen behave the same, and how do I get the touch inputs on my screen? I've tried the Windows 7 Touch pack that microsoft released. And the multi touch features seems to work there.

Any suggestion on how to proceed with this?

Comment: what version of wpf are you using?

Comment: Wich ever version of WPF that comes with a normal Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4 installation.

Comment: ok, just checking.  I *think* you should have everything you need, then.  I am on VS2008 still and IIRC you have to install libraries to get it to work on 3.5SP1.

Answer (score 2):

Event touchstart WORKS but touchend not. You can use onmouseup="SOMEfun()" 
Even the Samsung Galaxy 3 is a problem with the trigger event.
Add the first event and thay  will be working on but
Two scenario : 
1)first add onmouseup and than tauchstart  or  better
2)check mobile or desktop and than add proper events
You can use my detectbrowser function , its very nice (give a name of browser type like mobile_chrome_android_tablet or firefox_desktop , safari_ipad)

Make NOMOBILE global , you can simply replace var NOMOBILE =0; with window["NOMOBILE"]=0;

download  browser and device detector : 
[detect browser and device also class](https://maximumroulette.com/visual-js/lib/init.js)

Class name is DETECTBROWSER()

(on first line in script)

var BROWSER = new DETECTBROWSER()

Check this BROWSER.NAME

This is even crazy't script . Track 10 fingers at same time (in canvas2d)
link : https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/multi-touch-canvas-handler

**example for 1)**

```
      document.getElementById('myCanvas').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault(); 
        var touch = event.touches[0]; 
        /* Avatar go left */
          if (touch.pageX < 235) {
        if (backgroundX < 0){
         left = 1;
         }
        /* Avatar go right */
         if (touch.pageX > 470) {
         right=1;
         }
        /* Avatar go lower distance */
         if (touch.pageX > 235 && touch.pageX < 470 && touch.pageY >250 ) {
         distance--;
         }
        /* Avatar go to high distance */
         if (touch.pageX > 235 && touch.pageX < 470 && touch.pageY <250 )  {
         distance++; 
        }
         } ,false);
        // solution for touchend
          function ENDoff(){

           if (moveLEFT==1) {  moveLEFT=0;  }
           if (moveRIGHT==1) { moveRIGHT=0;  }
          }

HTML CODE 
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="960" onmouseup="touch_UP();"></canvas>
```