# Which events are acceptable for starting HTML5 audio play in mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, audio

Mobile browsers require *user action* to start play on Audio elements. The **click** event satisfies the requirement, but it appears that **touchstart** is not an acceptable initiating event in Chrome on Android or iOS. (See below)

Does anyone know where to find a precise definition of the event context required to start play.

(I was attempting to solve a UX problem using the ideas in  [How to prevent doubletap zoom in iOS and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804296/how-to-prevent-doubletap-zoom-in-ios-and-android).  Since posting my original question, I've found a solution that solves the UX problem without using **touchstart**, but I think the essential question about which events are considered to be user action is still valid.)

Addendum:

It has been suggested that I am mistaken about **touchstart** events, so for the record, I am providing a trivial test program.  Since it requires a real music file and a mobile device, JSFiddle isn't a suitable platform (unless somebody knows how to simulate a touchstart event in a fiddle).  To reproduce my observations, edit the javascript to load your own audio file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<br>
<button type="button" id="but1">click</button>
<button type="button" id="but2">touch</button>
<br>
<br>
<span id="message"></span>

<script>

var e;

e = document.getElementById('but1');
e.onclick = click;
e = document.getElementById('but2');
e.ontouchstart = touchstart;

function click() {
  alert('caught click');
  play();
  event.preventDefault();
}

function touchstart() {
  alert('caught touchstart');
  play();
  event.preventDefault();
}

var p;
var t;

function play() {

  p = new Audio();
  p.src = '/k487.mp3';      //  CHANGE THIS
  p.preload = 'auto';
  p.play();

  t = setInterval(report,1000);
}

function report() {

  var s = 'Player readyState='+p.readyState+', currentTime='+p.currentTime;
  var e = document.getElementById('message');

  e.innerHTML = s;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load this page in Chrome 58 on Android 6.0.1 the Click button works as expected, producing a popup, playing some music and updating the play time.

If I reload the page and touch the Touch button instead,  I get the popup, but no music plays.  The status display shows a readyState of 4 and a currentTime of 0.  In other words, the **touchstart** event is permitted to load the audio but not to initiate play.

Since I can find no documentation on what events are meant to work, I don't know whether to consider this a Chrome bug, or intended behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I did but I'm using a javascript framework (CreateJS) for this. They have perfectly explained the problem here: http://createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/. Maybe you should read it, it may give you some hints on how to fix it.

Comment: As far as I can see, your reference offers only the standard **onclick** solution.  The question is whether any other events can start play - **touchstart** does NOT work.

Comment: I think you're right. Touchstart will NOT work. I read articles of people gotten this to work on touchend, but touchend is not really the best option because it could never fire (for example when your finger moves a bit in the touchstart event). I think the only stable option to use the 'click' event.

Answer (score 1):

When the play() method on a media element is invoked, the user agent must run the following steps https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-play

> step1: if the media element is not allowed to play...

then I wonder the condition that allowed to play, it jump to here https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#allowed-to-play

it says:

> For example, a user agent could require that playback is triggered by user activation, but an exception could be made to allow playback while mute

then came to 'triggered-by-user-activation' [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation)
I think that's the reason:

> An algorithm is triggered by user activation if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> The task in which the algorithm is running is currently processing an activation behavior whose click event's isTrusted attribute is true.
>
> - change
> - click
> - contextmenu
> - dblclick
> - mouseup
> - pointerup
> - reset
> - submit
> - touchend

'touchstart' is not mentioned there.

hope that helps you.

Comment: Seems like this list is a more theoretical. On mobile chrome the touchend event also throws the exception that media playback is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194898/html5-audio-multiple-play) you will found answer on this question .

Use some popup or any animation nice for eye to attract user for tap .

in my memory ... android and iOS have no same behavior it is about max number of audios that we can start buffer with this trick  .

```
    var EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = false;

    document.addEventListener("touchstart" , function(e) {

    if (EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME == false){
    EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = true;

    document.getElementById("LaserShot").play(); // need for play pause just for buffering start
    document.getElementById("LaserShot").pause();
    // now you can play programmability from js 
    document.getElementById("LaserShot_CLONE").play();
    document.getElementById("LaserShot_CLONE").pause();

    }
  else if(EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = true){

    document.getElementById("MakeReadyotherAudio1").play();
    document.getElementById("MakeReadyotherAudio1").pause();

     EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = 'NOMORE'

  } 


    }
```

If you have problems i can make you code snippet with working example !

I put in 90% in mobile web dev in event function on begin :

```
   document.getElementById("myAnchor").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

//Sometimes even if you dont use some event its good to override :

```
  window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
      e.preventDefault()

    }, false)

    window.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()

    }, false)

    window.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){    
        e.preventDefault()


    }, false)

    window.addEventListener('touchleave', function(e){    
        e.preventDefault()


    }, false)
    window.addEventListener('touchcancel', function(e){    
        e.preventDefault()


    }, false)
    window.addEventListener('touchenter', function(e){    
        e.preventDefault()


    }, false)
```

If you wanna you can use this library : 
 [desktop/mobile event optimise for canvas](https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js/src/4903ba03f2c41731f9e24ce745421f8a6f09f1a4/project/program_instance/lib/game_object/game_object_events.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question.   You appear to acknowledge that an initial **click** on something is required to start the player.

Comment: "touchstart is not an acceptable initiating event " this is no true . Look possibly bug track : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794769/manipulation-and-touch-events-not-firing-but-mouse-events-do/13610808#13610808  I always use for mobile only touch events.

Comment: I've added my evidence to the original question.